# TextView border doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, xml

I wanted to make border for my TextView with these lines of xml code which I make in res/drawable. But border did not appear.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#FAF9F9"/>
</shape>
```

and this is my activityMain.xml where textView is:

```
<TextView
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="1. If you somehow found a way to extract all of the gold from the bubbling core of our lovely little planet, you would be able to cover all of the land in a layer of gold up to your knees."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: your border is there but it is mixing with white color you have used as backgroud. use some other color and try.

Answer (score 0):

example `border_bg.xml`

`

```
<!-- View background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@color/background_color" >
</solid>

<!-- View border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/border_color" >
</stroke>

<!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"   >
</corners>
```

`

and set it as a background in your textview

`android:background="@drawable/border_bg"`

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to give boundary color little bit dark as your code is working totally fine as color is so lights it is barely visible so try with black color or any color you want and even after giving dark color also it is not working let me know . make change it your code like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#000000"/> /*change here android:color*/ 

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Border not Appear because you have give border color same as background color. give it different like below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

now set this xml as background of text view like below

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/border_style"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="1. If you somehow found a way to extract all of the gold from the 
     bubbling core of our lovely little planet, you would be able to cover all of the 
     land in a layer of gold up to your knees."
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

that its.!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot see the border because it blends with your background color

a drawable like that will "work" for you to see

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#FAF9F9"/>
</shape>
```

also consider adding a padding to your TextView with the same size as your border (so 4dp) `android:padding="4dp"`

```
<TextView
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="1. If you somehow found a way to extract all of the gold from the bubbling core of our lovely little planet, you would be able to cover all of the land in a layer of gold up to your knees."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```